# Access to mpmath module in sympy (python)

Tags: python, sympy, mpmath

I am new to sympy and still naive about python.... I wanted to solve a trigonometric equation, to find its zeroes. (Once I have syntax, then I will use a more complex function.)

I cannot find the right syntax yet. Here is what I tried at the iPython console in Spyder (Python 2.7):

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
solve(sin(x), x)
```

I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       solve(sin(x), x)
>
> NameError: name 'sin' is not defined

OK, so I need to have the correct reference to the sine function.

According to the sympy documentation, I thought this was in `mpath`, but this did not work:

```
from mpmath import *
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-8dcdd12d9679>", line 1, in <module>
    from mpmath import *
```

> ImportError: No module named mpmath

How do I load/access mpmath or some other way to get the sine function?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it:

```
from sympy import sin
```

Answer (score 1):

To access mpmath do this

```
    from sympy.mpmath import *
```